# Getting Components by name not support all actions?

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, components

I have jTextField named "p0_1000"

And i use below methods can call it by name;

Creating Hashmap in class.

```
private HashMap componentMap;
```

Fill hashmap with components name.

```
private void createComponentMap() {
    componentMap = new HashMap<String,Component>();
    Component[] components = jDesktopPane1.getComponents();
    for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
            componentMap.put(components[i].getName(), components[i]);
    }
}
```

For call components by their names.

```
public Component getComponentByName(String name) {
    if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return (Component) componentMap.get(name);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

If i use directly p0_1000.setToolTipText("trying"); succesfully appear tooltiptext when mouse on releated textfield.

But if i use getComponentByName("p0_1000").setToolTipText("trying"); setToolTipText not recognized.

getComponentByName("p0_1000") succesfully working i tested. Because if i type "." after method name, avaliable action list come and i can use them (example .setVisible(false) working succesfully)

Some add, set or get commands not in avaliable action list when i call componen by name.

Any advice, idea, comments are appreciated.

Regards.

**---SOLVED---**

```
public JComponent getComponentByName(String name) {
    if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return (JComponent) componentMap.get(name);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Above changes solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your method is declared to return `Component` type, and if you look in the API for this class, you'll see that it does not have a `setToolTipText(...)` method. This method begins in the JComponent class.  One solution is to have the Map only collect JComponents and have the method declared to return this type. Incidentally, if you declare your Map with generic parameters, you won't have to do your cast.

i.e., rather than this declaration,

```
private HashMap componentMap;
```

use,

```
private HashMap<String, Component> componentMap;
```

or if again if this will work for you:

```
private HashMap<String, JComponent> componentMap;
```

Comment: You are right thanks. I turn my method getComponentByName to JComponent. But this time i cant use this method  in foor loop. Java says "Void type not allowed here" How can i use all of JComponents actions when call components by name ?

Comment: @BlackWhite: you've got a new different problem, one that you've yet to show us clearly, including the lines of code, etc. What for loop do you mean? We suck at reading minds or seeing code not shown. Consider asking this in a new question. You will need to show your code for this problem for us to understand it.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was use tooltiptex wrong bracket. I change public Component getComponentByName(String name) to public JComponent getComponentByName(String name) --- and  return (Component) componentMap.get(name); to  return (JComponent) componentMap.get(name); in same method. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should be using `JComponent` which is has [setToolTipText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29). If that's not what you want, you can check if the `java.awt.Component` is a `JComponent` and cast:

```
if (components[i]) instanceof JComponent) {
   JComponent jc = (JComponent) components[i];
   // now you can use setToolTipText
}
```